# Was I fired or let go?

Tags: human-resources

Before covid I was working at two places. One place let me go because I was no longer needed but offered me a job when covid settles down. The other place I had to limit my availability(due to transportation). I am collecting underemployment through PUA. Do I still qualify for underemployment because I lost a job because of covid or since I was let go/fired do I not qualify anymore. Do I qualify?

Comment: Depends on location, so you have to apply.

Comment: Please add a location tag, there is no way for us to tell you whether you qualify for an unknown benefit in an unknown country.

Comment: What Very Bad thing did you do to get fired?  I feel like you're leaving something out. Stealing? Sleeping on the job? Sexual harassment?  Failing to show up for work? Not having transportation isn't cause for firing.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Isn't not having transportation essentially the same thing as not showing up to work? You just know it's going to happen ahead of time.

Comment: Not necessarily. I.e. - I live in Poland. If I would work in germany, Poland effectively closing the border would mean a loss of transportation. Let me say this happened WITHOUT serious replanning and I know of doctors that got special dispensation and escort to the border to go back to their job on the german side.

Comment: @bsmp that turns rather sharply on what each of you knew, what you communicated, and the extenuating circumstances.  Say you are an executive secretary at American Airlines at LAX,  who commutes daily from SFO (your commute is a jump-seat on an airliner). You show up 6 hours late. Today is 9/11/01.  You don’t need to explain that one lol.

Comment: The location is Michigan. I was let go on technicality since I didn't work for 14 days the Menards system booted me out. I have asked my human resources manager and she confirmed I wasn't fired just let go on a technicality.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your state/province/country...

You **do** qualify for unemployment if your job was eliminated through no fault of your own, your hours were cut under a certain threshold, you were terminated for other causes (e.g. bad job fit), or you're furloughed for a certain time period (you don't get paid, but you keep your benefits).

You **do not** qualify for unemployment (or in this case, underemployment) assistance if you engage in gross misconduct, such as theft, intoxication, assault, breaching trust, embezzlement, etc.  Quitting a job also will disqualify you from unemployment.

IMHO, Job #1 let you go because you weren't needed, and Job #2 let you go because the job wasn't a good fit (transportation issues), so you should still qualify for underemployment assistance.

Your DUA (department of unemployment assistance) will help you if you have questions.

Comment: Also: Covid is a special case. Certification of slow business DUE TO it may change the situation and allow addiitonal aid programs, depending on judisduction (which the poster is absurdly light on).